# Pandas - Merging two dataframes by index ID

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 Dataframes as below:

**Dataframe1:**

```
   6     count
store_1   10
store_2   23
store_3   53
```

**Dataframe2:**

```
store_name  location
store_1     location_a
store_2     location_b
```

I am trying to join the above two Dataframes such that I get the below output:

```
   6     count  location
store_1   10    location_a
store_2   23    location_b
store_3   53
```

I am trying to merge `Dataframe1` with `Dataframe2` using index id of the column and not by the column name.

Comment: 6 is an index or a column? similarly `store_name ` ?

Comment: @anky_91, the first row are the column names. I am trying to build this such that it tries to join the two dataframes using the first column in each of the dataframes. Hence I am trying to join them by first column of the Dataframe

Comment: how does this work? `df1.set_index(6).combine_first(df.set_index('store_name'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Left merge on indexes would work for you.

```
data = {'6': ['store1', 'store2', 'store3'], 'count': [10, 23, 53]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('6')
df1
```

[image]

```
data = {'store_name': ['store1', 'store2'], 'location': ['location_a', 'location_b']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('store_name')
df2
```

[image]

```
df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

simply adds columns (axis=1) from df2 to 1st data frame